# How did Thanos know the stones were reduced to atoms?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In the beginning of *Avengers: Endgame*  we see:

> **NATASHA ROMANONFF**: Where are the Stones?
>
> **THANOS**: Gone. Reduced to atoms.
>
> **BRUCE BANNER**: You used them two days ago!
>
> **THANOS**: I used the stones to destroy the stones. It nearly killed me. But the work is done. It always will be. I am... inevitable.

When he used the stones to destroy them did they go dusted like in the process of Blip?

How does he know the stones were reduced to atoms? He just saw them to vanish? How didn't he think, for example, they are destroyed and vanished?

Comment: He wished them to be turned into atoms and they obliged.

Comment: Maybe they aren't and he doesn't know, maybe they were atoms for a microsecond and then some of them bounded (because that's what many atoms do: there is no "atomic oxygen" around), which is arguably indistinguishable from a normal chemical reaction that does not "reduce things to atoms", maybe he knowingly turned them to molecules instead of atoms and he's lying just to screw with everybody (including those who believe that he never lies)... The difference is immaterial.

Comment: My interpretation of that line is not a definitive "I know with 100% certainty the current state of the matter that formerly made up the stones", but more of a turn of phrase. "Reduced to dust", "reduced to nothing", "reduced to atoms". All the same way of saying "I've turned the stones into something that no one else can ever use to undo my actions".

Answer (score 0):

> How does he know the stones were reduced to atoms? He just saw them to vanish? How didn't he think, for example, they are destroyed and vanished?

He's probably being a little hyperbolic, but he used them to render each other unusable. Even if the stones weren't literally turned to atoms, the effect remains that the infinity stones were in a state where they were no longer usable.